# How to display multiple default items for field collection with unlimited cardinality?

Tags: 7, entities

I have used following code and it works fine i.e 3 items are displayed, but the issue in my code is add another item button remains inactive on click.

```
<?php

function two_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {


  if($form_id == 'product_culinary_node_form') {
    $field_language = $form['field_tabs']['#language'];
    $items_count = 3;

    $field_name = 'field_tabs';
    $form_theme = $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#theme'];

    // Remove delete and add more buttons
    // $form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['remove_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form[$field_name][$field_language]['add_more']['#access'] = TRUE;

    $items = &$form_state['field'][$field_name][$field_language];

    // Generate required number of fields collection
    if ($items_count > 1 && $items['items_count'] != $items_count) {
      $items['items_count'] = $items_count;

      // $items['field']['cardinality'] = $items_count;
      $wrapper = $form[$field_name][$field_language]['add_more']['#ajax']['wrapper'];
      $field_parents = $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#field_parents'];
      $language = $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#language'];
      $after_build = $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#after_build'];
      $form[$field_name][$field_language] = field_multiple_value_form($items['field'], $items['instance'], $field_language, array(), $form, $form_state);
      // Reset theme function, as field_multiple_value_form hijacks it
      $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#theme'] = $form_theme;
      $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#after_build'] = $after_build;
      $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#language'] = $language;
      $form[$field_name][$field_language]['#field_parents'] = $field_parents;
      $form[$field_name][$field_language]['add_more']['#ajax']['wrapper'] = $wrapper;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1337804), You might find something useful.

Comment: Yogesh, I have gone through almost all the patches and comments of the issue you have linked above and related posts. Nothing has worked till now.

Answer (score 0):

1 solution to this is https://www.drupal.org/node/1337804#comment-6326678. I will post another solution if found without form rebuild.